# How to map an Array of objects, that have arrays in the objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

My question is a bit hard to explain in the title.. but in react, I'm trying to map an element that looks like this

```
[
  { 
    logicLayer: { name: someName, etc }, 
    subComps: [ { name: anotherName, etc },{ name: anotherName, etc } ]
  },
  { 
    logicLayer: { name: someName, etc }, 
    subComps: [ { name: anotherName, etc },{ name: anotherName, etc } ]
  },
  etc
]
```

To a dropdown button menu

// This Works Fine

```
return (
        singular.buttonGroups.map(( buttonGroup, index1 ) =>
          buttonGroup.subComps.map(( subComp, index2 ) =>
            <MenuItem key={index2}><b>{buttonGroup.logicLayer.name}:</b> {subComp.name}</MenuItem>
          )
        )
      );
```

But what I really want to do is put a "divider" after it iterates the inner array.. something like this

// This Doesn't Work

```
return (
        singular.buttonGroups.map(( buttonGroup, index1 ) =>
          buttonGroup.subComps.map(( subComp, index2 ) =>
            <MenuItem key={index2}><b>{buttonGroup.logicLayer.name}:</b> {subComp.name}</MenuItem>
          )
            <MenuItem divider></MenuItem>  // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
        )
      );
```

How can I map this properly so that I can put a divider after it iterates the array of one of its objects?

EDIT: would be nice if there is a solution out there that doesn't require me to wrap it in a div container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it with some container:

```
return (
    singular.buttonGroups.map(( buttonGroup, index1 ) =>
      <div> 
          {buttonGroup.subComps.map(
             ( subComp, index2 ) =>
                <MenuItem key={index2}><b>{buttonGroup.logicLayer.name}:</b> {subComp.name}</MenuItem>
          )}
          <MenuItem divider></MenuItem>  // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
      </div>
    )
  );
```

Comment: it worked thank you!  the div does seem to mess up the CSS.. but at least I understand why my original code didn't work.. ty again

Comment: You are welcome :) You can change the `div` to any other element (or use css to fix the styling).